# Does Visual Studio provide the C library’s isnormal()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I’m building a C++ library with Visual Studio Express 2013. I’d like to call [the `isnormal` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal) from `cmath`, but the VS library only seems to have `_isnan` and `_finite` (and they’re in `cfloat`, not `cmath`).

It also provides `_fpclass`, which I assume corresponds to [`fpclassify`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify). Is the following macro a suitable replacement for `isnormal`?

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define isnormal(x) (_fpclass(x) == _FPCLASS_NN || _fpclass(x) == _FPCLASS_PN)
#endif
```

Comment: Try the `<cmath>` header instead...

Comment: @Mgetz Nope, there’s no `isnormal` in there.

Comment: @Mgetz …although of course you’re right that this stuff *should* be in `<cmath>`. I’ve tweaked my question.

Comment: Well a quick grep using powershell shows that in my install of VS2013 express it is actually there: `src\cmath:96:using _CSTD isnan; using _CSTD isnormal;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?Redirected=true) `isnormal` is at least present in MSVC2013's `<math.h>`. Therefore, in `<cmath>` you *should* find the corresponding `std::isnormal` (You remembered to use namespace std, right?). If not, you'll have to fall back to the C header.

(Or maybe fix/update your MSVC installation - MGetz' comment shows that his VS2013 Express installation has `std::isnormal`)

Comment: I don’t see the string “isnormal” in either `math.h` or `cmath`. As far as I can tell my VS installation is up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: @bdesham verify you are using the v120 sdk and not v100 or v110. I can assure you it's there in my installation.

Comment: @bdesham Do you use the right include path? Did you per chance copy old project files with fixed include paths to some older version? Does the path of the headers you searched in match your VS2013 installation?

Comment: The problem was my SDK version. I went to the Properties for my project, and under Configuration Properties > General I changed “Platform Toolset” to “Visual Studio 2013 (v120)”. Then `isnormal` was available by #including `<cmath>`. Thanks all!